# How to write pyspark map-reduce to compute number of events prior to date

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables let's call them users, events

```
users: [user_id, activity_date]
       [123,     4-28-2020    ]
       [456,     4-27-2020    ]

events: [user_id, event_date]
       [123,     5-28-2020    ]
       [456,     4-27-2020    ]
       [456,     4-25-2020    ]
       [456,     4-30-2020    ]
       [456,     1-30-2020    ]
       [123,     1-28-2020    ]
```

I'd like to get a rollup table that shows for each user the count of events in the events table prior to the value stored in users.activity_date.

So the above example would yield:

```
[user_id, total]
[123,       1  ]
[456,       3  ]
```

I tried using correlated queries and doing this on redshift, but it does not complete (there are millions of records in the first table, and tens of millions in the second)... so my thought is to use map reduce... but I'm not sure where to start. I can read the tables in pyspark and that's about where I get stuck.

Comment: Can you share your Redshift SQL as I expect you have an issue there.  10M rows is small for Redshift so if your query didn't complete there is likely an issue with it.

Comment: @user491880 Please accept and upvote the answer if it resolved your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you needed to was a `join`, find whether `event_date` greater than `activity_date` and `sum`

```
# create data frames
events_df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
("123","5-28-2020"),
("456","4-27-2020"),
("456","4-25-2020"),
("456","4-30-2020"),
("456","1-30-2020"),
("123","1-28-2020")], 
("user_id","event_date"))

events_df.show()
+-------+----------+
|user_id|event_date|
+-------+----------+
|    123| 5-28-2020|
|    456| 4-27-2020|
|    456| 4-25-2020|
|    456| 4-30-2020|
|    456| 1-30-2020|
|    123| 1-28-2020|
+-------+----------+


users_df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
("123","4-28-2020"),
("456","4-27-2020")], 
("user_id","activity_date"))

users_df.show()
+-------+-------------+
|user_id|activity_date|
+-------+-------------+
|    123|    4-28-2020|
|    456|    4-27-2020|
+-------+-------------+

# Import functions
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# Join both data frames on user_id
df = events_df.join(f.broadcast(users_df), events_df.user_id == users_df.user_id, how='left_outer').select(events_df['user_id'], events_df['event_date'], users_df['activity_date'])

df.show()
+-------+----------+-------------+
|user_id|event_date|activity_date|
+-------+----------+-------------+
|    123| 5-28-2020|    4-28-2020|
|    456| 4-27-2020|    4-27-2020|
|    456| 4-25-2020|    4-27-2020|
|    456| 4-30-2020|    4-27-2020|
|    456| 1-30-2020|    4-27-2020|
|    123| 1-28-2020|    4-28-2020|
+-------+----------+-------------+

# find if event_date greater than activity_date if yes then assign zero else 1
df1 = df.withColumn('active', f.when(f.col('event_date') > f.col('activity_date'), 0).otherwise(f.lit(1)))
df1.show()
+-------+----------+-------------+------+
|user_id|event_date|activity_date|active|
+-------+----------+-------------+------+
|    123| 5-28-2020|    4-28-2020|     0|
|    456| 4-27-2020|    4-27-2020|     1|
|    456| 4-25-2020|    4-27-2020|     1|
|    456| 4-30-2020|    4-27-2020|     0|
|    456| 1-30-2020|    4-27-2020|     1|
|    123| 1-28-2020|    4-28-2020|     1|
+-------+----------+-------------+------+

# then group by and sum
df2 = df1.groupby("user_id").agg(f.sum('active').alias('total'))
df2.show()
+-------+-----+
|user_id|total|
+-------+-----+
|    456|    3|
|    123|    1|
+-------+-----+
```

I have added a `broadcast`  join as you said one table is having `million` records and other having `tens of millions` records.

You can also combine `df` and `df1` as one like below

```
df = events_df.join(f.broadcast(users_df), events_df.user_id == users_df.user_id, how='left_outer').select(events_df['user_id'], events_df['event_date'], users_df['activity_date']).withColumn('active', f.when(f.col('event_date') > f.col('activity_date'), 0).otherwise(f.lit(1)))
```